# Handling swipes with modal pages

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a modal page that contains an absolute layout `space` in which I insert my widgets, in particular a **scrollable** list widget, which is a custom class derived from `AbsoluteLayout`:

```
    public ListWidget(List<ListItem> items)
    {
        list_items = items;

        BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;

        tap = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        tap.Tapped += Tap_Handler;

        list = new ListView()
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
            HasUnevenRows = true,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        };

        list.ItemTapped += Tap_Handler;
        list.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CustomCell));
        list.ItemsSource = list_items;

        SetLayoutBounds(list,  new Rectangle(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0));
        SetLayoutFlags(list, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
        Children.Add(list);
    }
```

Nothing fancy, as you see. Now, the page (a `ContentPage`) in question is loaded by a `PushModalAsync()` call, but here comes the problem:

If I swipe down on the list, the modal page gets **hidden** and I cannot get it back, since when I try I get this warning:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <Xamarin_Forms_Platform_iOS_ModalWrapper: 0x7f970601c580> on <Xamarin_Forms_Platform_iOS_PageRenderer: 0x7f9703f54b50> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Apparently, no `PopModalAsync()` is called in this case.

I have tried overriding this by using a gesture recognizer:

```
        // in the constructor...
        space.GestureRecognizers.Add(swipeDown);
        listwidget.GestureRecognizers.Add(swipeDown);
    }

    // where my hopes crushed
    void Swiper_Handler(object sender, SwipedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("SWIPED sender {0} args {1}", sender, e);

        if (sender == listwidget)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("LIST WIDGET! ABORT!");
            return;
        }

        switch (e.Direction)
        {
            case SwipeDirection.Left:
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Swiped to LEFT");
                break;
            case SwipeDirection.Right:
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Swiped to RIGHT");
                break;
            case SwipeDirection.Up:
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Swiped to UP");
                break;
            case SwipeDirection.Down:
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Swiped to DOWN");
                Navigation.PopModalAsync();
                break;
        }
    }
```

But it won't work:

- enabling swipe down on `space` will pop the page, but I cannot scroll the list
- enabling swipe down on `listwidget` will **hide** the page, I cannot scroll the list, and I get the above error
- removing gestures will **hide** the page, I cannot scroll the list, and I get the above error
- enabling swipe on both `space` and `listwidget` will pop the page, but I cannot scroll the list

How can I make a scrollable list with a modal page coexist?

Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will this error occur on the Android platform? For this issue, here is a similar case link you can refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41241508/xamarin-forms-warning-attempt-to-present-on-whose-view-is-not-in-the-window

Comment: @y3z1 no, on Android the two widgets coexist peacefully.

Comment: Hi, did you try the solution of the above link? Will it work?